# Black rectangles on Android's EditText when a GoogleMap V2 is used and the virtual keyboard is opened

Tags: android, google-maps, surfaceview, google-maps-android-api-2

This only happens on Android 2.x. If you put a `GoogleMapFragment` on a screen that scrolls when the software keyboard is shown, part of your other widgets will be overlaid with black rectangles.

[image: black rectangles]

This seems to be related with https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11676. As far as I know, the new V2 GoogleMap uses `SurfaceView` to draw, but we do not have access to the `SurfaceView` directly.

P.S. Actually this is a variation of [Android's EditText is hidden when the virtual keyboard is shown and a SurfaceView is involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978290/androids-edittext-is-hidden-when-the-virtual-keyboard-is-shown-and-a-surfacevie). I post this here to increase visibility, since this is a common Google Map V2 problem. If you think this should be a community question, please let me know or just change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse the view hierarchy and look for the view that is instance of `SurfaceView`. This worked for me.

If you are going to use the below code, call `traverse()` at the end of `onCreate` or any time the Google Map fragment has been added to your activity.

```
void traverse() {
    View root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    traverse(root, 0);
}

void traverse(View v, int depth) {
    if (v instanceof SurfaceView) {
        SurfaceView sv = (SurfaceView) v;
        sv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0, len = vg.getChildCount(); i < len; i++) {
            traverse(vg.getChildAt(i), depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```